# Question re: Chapman-Kolmogorov equations - iteration.

Tags: probability, markov-chains

the probability book that I am using proves the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations for $P(m,m+n+r) = P(m,m+n)P(m+n,m+n+r)$ and then says it follows by iteration that $P(m,m+n)$=$P^n$ - what does this iteration look like step-by-step?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One explanation of this is given in theorem (7) on p. 215 in Grimmet and Stirzaker: Probability and Random Processes 3rd ed.

The state transition matrix for a Markov Chain is given as $\textbf{P}(m,m+1)$, where the $(i,j)$'th entry $p_{ij}(m,m+1)$ is the probability that, when the chain is in state $i$ at time $m$, it goes to state $j$ in the next time step, which is $m+1$.

The state probability matrix of $n$ state transitions is then given by $\textbf{P}(m,m+n)$.

If the Markov Chain is homogeneous, the state transition matrix doesn't depend on $m$, so $p_{ij}(m,m+1) = p_{ij}(m',m'+1)$, for all $m \neq m'$, meaning that   $\textbf{P}(m,m+1) = \textbf{P}(m',m'+1)$.

We then have that $\textbf{P}(m,m+1) = \textbf{P}$ for arbitrary $m$. The two-step transition matrix can be written as

\begin{align}
\textbf{P}(m,m+2) &= \textbf{P}(m,m+1)\textbf{P}(m+1,m+2) \\ &=\textbf{P}(m,m+1)\textbf{P}(m',m'+1) \\ &=\textbf{P} \cdot \textbf{P} \\ &= \textbf{P}^2,
\end{align}

since the chain is homogeneous. Using the same argumentation, we can show that $\textbf{P}(m,m+3) = \textbf{P}^3$, and that $\textbf{P}(m,m+n)=\textbf{P}^n$.

Comment: Thank you - I just had some kind of mental block on this and could not work it out.